# Gulp не создает папку dist

Tags: gulp

Это происходит при внедрении в новый проект

Ошибок в терминале нет

Path.js

```
// Получаем имя папки проекта
import * as nodePath from 'path';
const rootFolder = nodePath.basename(nodePath.resolve());


const buildFolder = "./dist"; // Также можно rootFolder
const srcFolder = "./src";

export const path = {
    build: {
            js: `${buildFolder}/js/`,
            css: `${buildFolder}/css/`,
            html: `${buildFolder}/`,
            images: `${buildFolder}/img/`,
            fonts: `${buildFolder}/fonts/`,
            files: `${buildFolder}/files/`,
    },
    src: {
            js: `${srcFolder}/js/app.js`,
            images: `${srcFolder}/img/**/*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif,webp}`,
            svg: `${srcFolder}/img/**/*.svg`,
            scss: `${srcFolder}/scss/style.scss`,
            html: `${srcFolder}/*.html`, //.pug
            files: `${srcFolder}/files/**/*.*`,
            svgicons: `${srcFolder}/svgicons/*.svg`,
    },
    watch: {
        js: `${srcFolder}/js/**/*.js`,
        scss: `${srcFolder}/scss/**/*.scss`,
        html: `${srcFolder}/**/*.html`,
        images: `${srcFolder}/img/**/*.{jpg,jpeg,png,svg,gif,ico,webp}`,
        files: `${srcFolder}/files/**/*.*`,
    },
    clean: buildFolder,
    buildFolder: buildFolder,
    srcFolder: srcFolder,
    rootFolder: rootFolder,
    ftp: "test",
}
```

Gulpfile.js

```
// Основной модуль
import gulp from "gulp";
// Импорт путей
import { path } from "./gulp/config/path.js";
// Импорт общих плагинов
import { plugins } from "./gulp/config/plugins.js";

// Передаем значения в глобальную переменную
global.app = {
    isBuild: process.argv.includes('--build'),
    isDev: !process.argv.includes('--build'),
    path: path,
    gulp: gulp,
    plugins: plugins
}

// Импорт задач
import { copy } from "./gulp/tasks/copy.js";
import { reset } from "./gulp/tasks/reset.js";
import { html } from "./gulp/tasks/html.js";
import { server } from "./gulp/tasks/server.js";
import { scss } from "./gulp/tasks/scss.js";
import { js } from "./gulp/tasks/js.js";
import { images } from "./gulp/tasks/images.js";
import { otfToTtf, ttfToWoff, fontsStyle } from "./gulp/tasks/fonts.js";
import { svgSprive } from './gulp/tasks/svgSprive.js';
import { zip } from './gulp/tasks/zip.js';
import { ftp } from './gulp/tasks/ftp.js';

// Наблюдатель за изменениями в файлах
function watcher() {
    gulp.watch(path.watch.files, copy);
    gulp.watch(path.watch.html, html); //gulp.series(html, ftp)
    gulp.watch(path.watch.scss, scss);
    gulp.watch(path.watch.js, js);
    gulp.watch(path.watch.images, images);
}

export { svgSprive }

// Последовательная обработка шрифтов
const fonts = gulp.series(otfToTtf, ttfToWoff, fontsStyle);

// Основные задачи
const mainTasks = gulp.series (fonts, gulp.parallel(copy, html, scss, js, images));

// Построение сценариев выполнения задач
const dev = gulp.series(reset, mainTasks, gulp.parallel(watcher, server));
const build = gulp.series(reset, mainTasks);
const deployZIP = gulp.series(reset, mainTasks, zip);
const deployFTP = gulp.series(reset, mainTasks, ftp);

// Экспорт сценариев
export { dev }
export { build }
export { deployZIP }
export { deployFTP }

// Выполнение сценария по умолчанию
gulp.task('default', dev);
```

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "gulp-2023",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "gulpfile.js",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "gulp",
    "build": "gulp build --build",
    "zip": "gulp deployZIP --build",
        "deploy": "gulp deployFTP --build",
    "svgSprive": "gulp svgSprive"
  },
  "author": "Nic Qape",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "browser-sync": "latest",
    "del": "latest",
    "gulp": "latest",
    "gulp-autoprefixer": "latest",
    "gulp-clean-css": "latest",
    "gulp-file-include": "latest",
    "gulp-fonter": "latest",
    "gulp-group-css-media-queries": "latest",
    "gulp-if": "latest",
    "gulp-imagemin": "latest",
    "gulp-newer": "latest",
    "gulp-notify": "latest",
    "gulp-plumber": "latest",
    "gulp-rename": "latest",
    "gulp-replace": "latest",
    "gulp-sass": "latest",
    "gulp-svg-sprite": "latest",
    "gulp-ttf2woff2": "latest",
    "gulp-util": "latest",
    "gulp-version-number": "latest",
    "gulp-webp": "latest",
    "gulp-webp-html-nosvg": "latest",
    "gulp-webpcss": "latest",
    "gulp-zip": "latest",
    "sass": "latest",
    "vinyl-ftp": "latest",
    "webp-converter": "2.2.3",
    "webpack": "latest",
    "webpack-stream": "latest"
  }
}
```

Comment: а что в тасках? типо этого - import { copy } from "./gulp/tasks/copy.js"; может пути не догрузили в них?

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос закрыт, я забыл написать `npm run build` , после того как написал, папка dist появилась